# Access an Entity Query in Linq -- Lightswitch application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am using lightswitch. Now i have an entity name: Jobs and that entity "Jobs" has a query item name Query1. Now i would like to access Query1 using linq.

```
var qryUser = ds.sspData.Jobs.Where(a => a.UserName.Contains(uName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

That is a linq query on the entity Jobs. I want a linq query on Query1. I am not figuring it. help me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out:

```
var q = (from a in ds.sspData.Query1() select a).Execute().ToList();
```